# How to sort a dictionary by a value where the value is an element in a list?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
D={'CA':[1,2], 'AZ':[5,2], 'NY':[2,7]}
```

I want to sort this by the 1st element in the value list in descending order, which should end up like this:

```
D={'AZ':[5,2], 'NY':[2,7], 'CA':[1,2]}
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered, you can't sort them.

Comment: See the referenced duplicate question.  Lists sort naturally in the order you want, so you can trivially adapt that answer for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really sort a dictionary, but you can get its keys in the sorted order that you described, and use that to make a sorted list of tuples:

```
sorted_keys = sorted(D, key = D.get, reverse = True)
#equivalently
sorted_keys = sorted(D, key = lambda x: D[x], reverse = True)
print [(key, D[key]) for key in sorted_keys]
#sort by 2 element
sorted_keys = sorted(D, key = lambda x: D[x][1], reverse = True)
```

### Output:

[('AZ', [5, 2]), ('NY', [2, 7]), ('CA', [1, 2])]

Comment: What about if i want to sort by the 2nd element in the list above, instead of the 1st element?

Comment: ok. I think figured it out. just do:  key=D.get(1)

Comment: i added a sort by the second element.  the key has to be a function that takes in the element and produces a value by which the element is sorted

Comment: you could sort an ordered dict from the collections module, fwiw :)